# Sort sequence of tasks such that the tasks in the sequences occur connected

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, np

I have given a set of sequences `S` containing integer values (where each integer value can be identified with a task). My goal is to sort `S` such that I do not have to interrupt a task. That is, if I place an element `S_i` which contains task 3 I want that all sets `S_j` which also contain 3 are placed directly after `S_i`.

For example,

`S = {S_1 = {1,5},S_2={1,3,4}, S_3={5}}`

I find a sorting of `S` such that the values in the sequences are not interrupted.
That is `S_1 -> S_2 -> S_3` is not a legal sorting because `S_1` contains '5' but is succeeded by `S_2` which does not contain '5'. The valid sorting would be `S_3->S_1->S_2`

Second Example

`S= {S_1 = {1,2,3} , S_2 = {2,4} , S_3={4,5}}` is already correctly sorted

Third Example

`S= {S_1={1,2}, S_2={2,3}, S_3={1,3}}` cannot be correctly sorted.

Last Example

`S={S_1={1,2,3}, S_2={5,6,7}, S_3={3,6}}` can be sorted `S_1 -> S_3 -> S_2`

My question is now how to model this and if there is an algorithm for it. The algorithm could for the first step just decide if it is possible to sort it or not. I does not have to perform the sorting.

I already tried and figured out that it is possible to solve if I have only two elements per `S_i`.
I, however, have trouble to extend it for the case that there are 3 or more elements.

Answer (score 0):

Think of this as a graph theory problem, where the nodes are the sets. Two nodes are adjacent if they need to go next to each other. I.e., put an edge between S_i and S_j if they contain a common element.

The only case than can be correctly sorted is if

1. Every node in the resulting graph has degree <= 2, and
2. The graph is acyclic.

Here are some examples.

```
S = {S_1 = {1,5},S_2={1,3,4}, S_3={5}}
Nodes: S1, S2, S3 (the sets)
Edges: (S1,S2), (S1,S3)
S2 & S3 have degree 1, and S1 has degree 2.
Solutions are: S2, S1, S3, and S3, S1, S2.
```

In this case, start with either node of degree one, and follow edges (there will only every be one choice) until you run out. Then, either you're done, or you pick another node of degree one and repeat.

```
S= {S_1={1,2}, S_2={2,3}, S_3={1,3}}
Edges: (S1,S2), (S1,S3), (S2,S3)
Solutions: None; there's a cycle
```

Simple Algorithm:

- Construct the graph as described, stopping if any node has degree >= 3 (a third edge) because there's no solution.
- If the graph ever reaches a state where all nodes have degree 2 then there's no solution.
- Start with a node of degree one. Follow the only possible path from that node until you must stop. Then, pick another node of degree one and repeat.

Comment: Hey Dave, thanks for your reply.
That is what I also thought first. Consider the following  
S_1={1,2} , S_2={1,3} , S_3={1,4} and S_4={4} 
It is obviously sorted correctly however the "Node" S_3 in the graph has 3 incoming edges and there is a cycle S1,S2,S3. I think one somehow has to adjust the logi in a way like :
There is no cycle => Detect all cycles and remove those where all the nodes share at least one integer??
The degree is <=2 => Determine the degree of each node and substract the number of doubly counted edges in the sense only count the edge for each task (integer) ones.

Comment: @FlorianSpeicher In the example you gave above, there's no way to have all the '1' jobs adjacent. I.e., you could do [2,1] [1,3] [1,4] [4], but then there's a 3 between two of the '1' jobs. If that doesn't interrupt the '1' job then I must be misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: @FlorianSpeicher From your comment, I take it that any solution where all sets containing a given value are adjacent is valid?